# In Nginx, "etag" directive doesn't work for proxy_pass?

Tags: http, nginx, https, etag

I'm using Nginx 1.9.2 and following is my configuration

```
upstream httpserver0{
            server 127.0.0.1:35011  max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s; #H_server0                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}

server {
            listen       443 ssl;
            listen       80;
            server_name  11.22.33.44; #my_server_name                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            etag  on;

            location  ~* \.(ts|raw)$ {
              set $server_id "0";
              if ( $uri ~ ^/(.*cfs+)/(.*)$ ){
                set $server_id $1;
              }
              if ( $server_id = "4cfs" ){
                proxy_pass  http://httpserver0$request_uri;
              }
            }
}
```

I'm using [upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) and proxy_pass for reverse proxy, and I enabled etag function by `etag on` within the server block.

However, when I check the Header of HTTP response, I didn't find the `etag` field at all..

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not work for `proxy_pass`.

http://nginx.org/r/etag

> Enables or disables automatic generation of the “ETag” response header field for **static resources**.

Even more, it's turned on by default.

Comment: Thanks, so nginx can't add `etag` for reverse proxy. It seems that the only way is to add etag to the upstream source. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. Only upstream knows how to generate Etag and when it should be considered obsolete.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Eh, a proxy could generate 'strong' (i.e. content hash) etags, and revalidate per request with upstream, returning 304 if upstream didn't change. This would be a very nice bandwidth reduction between nginx and clients. Taking that further, one could also specify a revalidation interval, or use Expires to trigger revalidation instead of revalidating per-client-request.

Comment: Does proxy pass handle If-match or if-none-match? My server application uses these and work on development but not on a (plesk based) production server.